# Bind multiple values directly from list without binding the list itself

Tags: let-binding

Is it possible to assign multiple return values directly to variables without going through a temporary variable in Emacs Lisp?

For example, let's say I have a function that returns a list of two lists:

```el
(defun test-func ()
  (setq a '(a b))
  (setq b '(c d))
  `(,a ,b))
```

If I want to assign the first return value to `list-a` and the second return value to `list-b`, I can do this by using a temporary variable `temp`, for example:

```el
(let* ((temp (test-func)) (list-a (car temp)) (list-b (cadr temp)))
  (message-box (prin1-to-string list-a))
  (message-box (prin1-to-string list-b)))
```

Is it possible to do this more simply? (I am used to Perl and Python where you do not have to specify a temporary variable)

Comment: You may try `cl-destructuring-bind` macro. Also, did you really intend to use `setq` inside a `defun`? `setq` creates a "special" (globally accessible) variable, something you'd typically put outside a function (because there's little meaning in declaring the same variable more than once, while functions are intended to be run more than once).

Comment: @wvxvw Thanks! Yes I forgot to use `let` inside the function.. I did not plan to set any global variables :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Common Lisp has a special facility - [multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22796346/850781), and [Emacs Lisp compatibility library](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Overview.html) [emulates them using lists](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Multiple-Values.html).

Thus you can do

```
(defun test-fun ()
  (let ((a 1) (b 2))
    (cl-values a b)))

(cl-multiple-value-bind (a b) (test-fun)
  ...)
```

(load `cl-lib` and use the `cl-` prefix for all CL functionality in EL).

**NB**: if you look at the SO answer linked above, you will see that emulating MV with lists is, to put it mildly, suboptimal (see also @Stefan's comment below).

Comment: Is there any advantage of using `multiple-value-bind` instead of `cl-multiple-value-bind` (only the latter seems to be documented in the manual https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Multiple-Values.html ) ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland They are the same function, but you should use the **latter**. The `cl` package is not meant to be used anymore. You should always use the `cl-lib` package instead, which defines functions with the `cl-` prefix..

Comment: I'd recommend against the use of `cl-values`: it's a "best effort" emulation of CommonLisp's `values` but it's not really compatible since all it does is return a list (i.e. it's kind of a lie), and in my experience people sooner or later end up manipulating those as lists (i.e. breaking the abstraction): better use lists explicitly (and if you don't like `pcase-let`, then use `cl-destructuring-bind` rather than `cl-multiple-value-bind`).

Answer (score 5):

Beside relying on the `cl-lib` compatibility package, the recommended way in Elisp for that is to use `pcase`:

```
(defun test-fun
  (let ((a '(a b))
        (b '(c d)))
    `(,a ,b)))

(defun other-test-fun ()
  (pcase-let ((`(,a ,b) (test-fun)))
    (message "a = %s; b = %s" a b)))
```

Beside `pcase-let`, there's also `pcase-dolist`, `pcase-lambda`, and `pcase` itself.